# SML/NJ: Extracting a number's digits into an int list

Tags: file, parsing, char, integer, ml

Input: text file that contains only 1 line with an integer in it

Output: int list with the number's digits

Here's my code:

```
fun parse file =
  let
    val input = TextIO.openIn file

    fun read_digits (NONE,acc) = rev acc
      | read_digits (SOME e,acc) =
        let
          val c = Option.valOf (e)
          val str = Char.toString c
          val digit = Option.valOf (Int.fromString str)
        in
          read_digits (TextIO.input1 input,digit::acc)
        end
  in
    read_digits (TextIO.input1 input,nil: int list)
  end
```

And here are the error messages that I'm getting:

```
test.sml:14.11-14.55 Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]
  operator domain: char option option * int list
  operand:         TextIO.elem option * int list
  in expression:
    read_digits (TextIO.input1 input,digit :: acc)
test.sml:17.5-17.52 Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]
  operator domain: char option option * int list
  operand:         TextIO.elem option * int list
  in expression:
    read_digits (TextIO.input1 input,nil: int list)

uncaught exception Error
  raised at: ../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:66.19-66.27
             ../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:44.55
             ../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:292.17-292.20
```

Any suggestions about how to deal with the problem?

Otherwise, does anyone have a better idea for extracting the digits of a number from a text file, into an int list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem here is that `e` in `SOME e` is already a `char`, you don't have to "unpack" it with `valOf`.

The second problem is that even after you remove that `valOf` (and your program will typecheck), an attempt to read digits from a file will result in a run-time error like this:

```
$ cat digits.txt
12345
$ smlnj read_digits_from_file.sml
...
- parse "digits.txt";

uncaught exception Option
  raised at: Basis/Implementation/option.sml:17.25-17.31
```

That is due to the end of line character(s). To remedy this, you could do something like this:

```
fun parse file =
  let
    val input = TextIO.openIn file

    fun read_digits (NONE, acc) = acc (* end of stream *)
      | read_digits (SOME ch, acc) =
        let
          val str = Char.toString ch
        in
          case (Int.fromString str) of
              SOME digit => read_digits (TextIO.input1 input, digit::acc)
            | NONE => acc (* return on first non-digit *)
        end
  in
    rev (read_digits (TextIO.input1 input, []))  (* rev moved here *)
```

A simple test:

```
- parse "digits.txt";
val it = [1,2,3,4,5] : int list
```

Comment: Thank you very much! :D
Also, you're right, I should check for the new line character. The only reason I didn't, is because I knew that the file contains only one line, so there wasn't any risk reading the '\n' character. But it's always better to be safe than sorry.
Thanks!

Comment: @Orion (1) for example `echo "12345" > digits.txt` will insert it (one can use the `-n` option to avoid though);  (2) you should also close file descriptors after you don't need a file anymore

Comment: (1) You're right, I created the file with an editor, in which case there wasn't added any unnecessary '\n'. (2) Noted. Thanks again! :)